# WAS7 and server Profile with multiple applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, profile, websphere-7

Where i work right now, they have about 60 apps (intranet and internet) running.  Most apps use a datasource, JMS Queues, Topics etc.

They use WebSphere and right now, each application have a specific profile that we have to import from a backup (.car). (when we create our local workspace)

I find this process heavy and time consuming.  **Is there any other way to have multiple applications with 1 profile on WAS 7?**.  I know we can define datasources in the application.xml, can we define JMS Queues, topics too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than importing a .car file you could have a wsadmin script that sets up datasources, queues, etc. for that application. I am not sure it will be any less time consuming for you though.